# Set theory and well-ordering

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $X \ne \emptyset, X \subseteq \omega$. Show that there is $n \in
>  X, n \cap X = \emptyset$

I am trying to solve this, but I'm a bit confused. It's stated in relation to the wellordering theorem. I think I need to state a set (which I don't know) and show it's inductive? Any hints?

Statement of WO Theorem: Let $X \subset \omega.$ Then either $X = \emptyset$ or there is an $x \in X$ so that for any $m \in X$ either $x=m$ or $x \in m$.

Comment: How is your version of the well-ordering theorem stated? If it simply says that each non-empty subset of $\omega$ has a least element, consider letting $n$ be that least element.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott edited q to include

Comment: Okay: show that the $m$ whose existence is ensured by the w-o theorem works for $n$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott if n=m doesn't the intersection =n?

Comment: Sorry: I misread your statement of the WO theorem. I meant for you to take $n=x$.

Comment: I think I'm getting there. If $n \in m$ then the intesection trivial otherwise we don't have least element. What if n=m though? Is the intersection not n?

Comment: By the WO theorem you have an $n\in X$ with the property that for any $k\in X$, either $n=k$ or $n\in k$. Now suppose that there is some $k\in n\cap X$. Then $k\in n$, so $k\ne n$. And $k\in X$, so ... ?

Comment: So $n \in k$, but then since $k \in n$, we have a contradiction so empty set?

Comment: Yes, assuming that you already know that it’s impossible to have both $k\in n$ and $n\in k$.